# What are the criteria for graduation from beta?

Tags: support

In reading about the recent beta design changes, I saw a mention of if/when we get graduate out of beta.  I did a quick bit of noodling around and found nothing on graduation from beta.

So, what are the criteria for a site to graduate from Beta to "full" status, and how close is RPG to reaching that goal?

Comment: sacrifice a goat or two to $deity and pray hard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There aren't any hard and fast rules, so far as I'm aware. StackExchange is kind of making things up as they go when it comes to graduation. Which is fair, since this is kind of a new thing in general.

The primary indicator for graduation at this time is site growth. When you plot the views per day against time, they want the graph to be increasing dramatically as it moves to the right.

We don't have that at this time. Our views are healthy, but they tend to be stable for a long period, followed by a spurt of growth, followed by a new (higher) plateau. We have yet to figure out how to achieve the continuous explosive growth required for graduation.

Comment: Also, having more than [3.7 questions a day](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games) might help...

Comment: I've spent some time thinking about this... I don't know whether "continuous explosive growth" is something we can expect from a niche interest like tabletop RPGs. There may be a surge when D&D 5/Next comes out, but that's not the same thing.